# Reading and Rearranging data in Python

Tags: python, matrix, file-read, large-data

I have a very large (10GB) data file of the form:

```
A  B   C   D   
1  2   3   4
2  2   3   4
3  2   3   4
4  2   3   4
5  2   3   4
1  2   3   4
2  2   3   4
3  2   3   4 
4  2   3   4
5  2   3   4
1  2   3   4
2  2   3   4
3  2   3   4
4  2   3   4
5  2   3   4
```

I would like to read just the B column of the file and rearrange it in the form

```
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2
```

it takes very long time to read the data and rearrange them, could some give me a very efficient method to do this in python

This is the code that I used for my MATLAB for processing the data

```
fid = fopen('hpts.out', 'r'); % Open text file
InputText = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', '\n'); % Read header lines
HeaderLines = InputText{1}
A = textscan(fid,'%n %n %n %n %n', 'HeaderLines', 1);


t  = A{1};
vz = A{4};

L = 1;

for j = 1:1:5000
   for i=1:1:14999

    V1(j,i) =  vz(L);
    L = L +1 ;
end

end

imagesc(V1);
```

Comment: I think reading 10 GB is just an inherently time consuming process. File IO is expensive and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: You could do a one time costly operation of inserting it into a database and then use that from then on, that could speed up future uses.

Comment: Show us the code that is slow.  Perhaps your code can be optimized or perhaps dealing with a 10GB file just takes a long time.  The code will tell the story.

Comment: How are the columns delimited?  Or are they fixed width?

Comment: The best answer to your question depends heavily on what you're wanting to do with the data.  Can you give us a bit more details? Do you just want to print it out similar to what you show, or are you doing further computations?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski : The columns are delimited by a character space ' '

Comment: @Bow could you post a little more contextual informations? You say you have working code, could you post it for instance?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I have added the Matlab code which I use, I am looking for something like this for python

Comment: @Jivan : Please check the code above

Answer (score 2):

You can us Python for this, but I think this is exactly the sort of job where a shell script is better, since it's a lot shorter & easier:

```
$ tail -n+2 input_file | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ' | fmt -w 10
```

- `tail` removes the first (header) line;
- `awk` gets the second column;
- `tr` puts it on a single line;
- and `fmt` makes lines a maximum of 10 characters.

Since this is a streaming operation, it should not take a lot of memory, and *most* performance for this is limited to just disk I/O (although shell pipes also introduce *some* overhead).

Example:

```
$ tail -n+2 input_file | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ' | fmt -w 10
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: This is a good answer if the column contains only single character entries.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, but that's what the example output looks like; but it's certainly possible that the "real" data doesn't. You could modify the (obviously) `awk` to work with other delimiters, multiple fields, etc.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker:  I get this error Apple@Bow:~$ awk '{print $2}' try.txt | paste -s -d ' ' | fmt -w 3
usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...

Comment: @Bow From your prompt, it looks like you're using OSX; which uses FreeBSD's `paste`, which doesn't read from stdin (only a file) meh ... I have modified it to use `tr`, which should work for OSX platforms (tested on Linux & FreeBSD).

Answer (score 0):

Dont't read the whole file at one time! Read the file line by line:

```
def read_data():
    with open("filename.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.split()[1]

with open('file_to_save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i, data in enumerate(read_data()):
        f.write(data)
        if i % 5 == 0:
            f.write('\n')
```

Comment: The admonishment not to read the whole file into memory is well taken, but I wonder why you think the OP needs it considering no code was posted.

Answer (score 0):

This streaming approach should perform well:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

with open('yourfile', 'r') as fin, open('newfile', 'w') as fout:
    # discard header row
    next(fin) 
    # make generator for second column
    col2values = (line.split()[1] for line in fin)
    # zip into groups of five.  
    # fillvalue used to make a partial last row look good.
    for row in izip_longest(*[col2values ]*5, fillvalue=''):
        fout.write(' '.join(row) + '\n')
```